# Angular module not available with esnext module config

Tags: angular, typescript, module

I'm currently working on updating a legacy codebase incrementally, and am running into some issues with modules/namcespaces.

We have a `models.ts` file which looks like this

```
angular.module('models', ['ngResource']);
import './company';
```

Inside `company.ts`, we declare a namespace with a factory function called `ACCompany`, after which we register to the `'models'` module

```
namespace Company {
  ....
  export function ACCompany(
  $log: ng.ILogService,
  $q: ng.IQService,
  $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService,
  conf: IACConf,
 ) { ... }
}

angular.module('models').factory('CompanyAPI', Company.ACCompany);
```

This used to work fine, but recently I changed the `module` key in `tsconfig` to be "esnext" and the `moduleResolution` key to be "node". Suddenly it seems like the 'models' module is unavailable.

Halp?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was basically that es6 modules are statically analyzed. So the code in `company.ts` was being executed before the code in `models.ts`.

My solution was creating another file which imported `models.ts` (first) and `company.ts` (second), and then changing `modles.ts` to just be the `angular.module('models', ['ngResource']);` statement